# Python .format() KeyError when using class.__dict__

Tags: python, string, class, format, keyerror

Basically I have a class defined and I'm trying to display its attributes in a print statement EDIT:

```
class Player(object):
    """ Default Class for the player """
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.class_type = '[CLASS]'
        self.level = 1
        self.health = 10
        self.maxhealth = self.level * 10
        self.attack = 0
        self.defence = 0
        self.experience = 0
        self.weapon = ''
        self.shield = ''
        self.player_y = 9
        self.player_x = 39

print('LV: {level} EXP: {exp} HP: {health}/' +
      '{maxhealth}'.format(**char))
```

Am I doing something wrong? I'm just trying to find a more efficient way to display attributes of a class rather than doing...

```
print(character.name + ': Weight: ' + character.weight + ' Age: ' +
      character.age + '...')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you forgot `self` in  `__init__`

Comment: ...and  `**` with `dict` in `format`, or use `format_map`(Python 3.2+) if you want to use a `dict`.

Comment: by `self` it means `self.name = name`, etc, because the way variables were assigned is limited only to the scope of the `__init__` method, and not to the instance of the object itself.

Comment: @user3100115 You're right I forgot it here but I have it in my actual source code, that was rushing on my part.

Comment: @Voks - please **copy-paste** your code into your question. Please do not re-type, summarize, or write new code in your question. Please copy-paste your actual code, along with your actual error message.

Comment: @Robᵩ Very sorry, was a poor choice on my part, I've updated the code.

Comment: Thanks, @Voks, for pasting in your actual code. What I failed to say is that you should copy-paste the shortest actual program that demonstrates the error. That is, you should reduce your real-world program to a short sample (which you did very well initially), and you test and then copy-paste *that* sample (which is where you fell down initially). For the sake of future questions, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Robᵩ Okay, I've shortened it, and will definitely read that before posting any further questions on Stack. Thanks for pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgotten to use `self.` in your `Player.__init__` function, and you've forgotten to use `**` in your call to `str.format`.

Here is working code:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.age = 125
        self.height = 72
        self.weight = 154
        self.sex = 'Male'

character = Player('NAME')

print('{name} {height} {weight} {sex}'.format(**character.__dict__))
```

Comment: Thank you, my problem was I used ** in my attempt but didn't use .__dict__ along with it. Thanks for your help.